# How to pass value to or call a function of AMyPlayerController (APlayerController) from UMenuWidget (UUserWidget) in Unreal, using C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-umg

My `UMenuWidget` (derived from `UUserWidget`) needs to pass a value to `AMyPlayerController` (derived from `APlayerController`).

I have tried:

```
DECLARE_DYNAMIC_MULTICAST_DELEGATE_OneParam(FPassParam,int,intData);
```

But `inGameHUD->MenuWidget` from `AMyPlayerController::BeginPlay()` returns *NULL*, likely because `MenuWidget` is yet to be created.
This prevents me from *add/bind*-ing of functions.

How can I do/solve this?

Kindly help me, please.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link to answer, at UE4 Answer Hub:
https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/1056641/how-to-pass-value-to-or-call-a-function-of-amyplay.html